# A Problem on quotient space of A Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = \{a_n| a_n$ is eventually constant sequence over$\mathbb{R}\}$

$W = \{a_n| a_n$ is eventually zero sequence over$\mathbb{R}\}$

Then I need to prove\disprove

$\dfrac{V}{W} = \{W + a_n\}$ such that $a_n = 1 \forall n \ldots (1)$

Now, this is what I did

$\dfrac{V}{W} = \{W + x_n\}$ such that $x_n \in V$

Since $x_n$ is eventually constant there exist some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$x_n = a$ $\forall n \ge k$

so this $W + a_n =  W + x_n  +y_n - y_n$ where $y_n = -a \forall n\ge k$

=$W - y_n$ since $x_n + y_n \in W$

Now, I am stuck I am trying to use this same technique so I can reduce this quotient space to the form  $(1)$ but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: The right side should be $\{W+c(a_n): c\in \mathbb R\}$ where $(a_n)=(1,1,...)$.

Comment: I don't think it's true. Take a constant sequence say $(x_n)$ such that $x_n=2$ for all $n$.